# If I change the current working directory, why does __file__ become invalid path?

Tags: python

Executing `test.py` from `/tmp`

```
import os

print os.path.abspath(__file__)
os.chdir('/var')
print os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

output:

```
/tmp/test.py
/var/test.py
```

I expected the second output to be `/tmp/test.py`. Is this a bug or expected behavior? Is there a way to get the actual location of the file that is not affect by `chdir`?

I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Because `__file__` is relative in your case, as it is the *exact samething* as what you passed to `python` on the command line. `os.path.abspath()` has no choice but to make it absolute based on the current working directory in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how you invoke the python script, `__file__` can be an absolute or a relative path (e.g. `python /tmp/test.py` for the former and `cd /tmp; python test.py` for the latter).

So if `__file__` is relative, `os.path.abspath` will use the current working directory as the base directory.

Easy to prove by adding `print __file__` to your test script.

Comment: Thanks. So what happen when you refer to " --file--"  from script that is pip installed? I assume it is an absolute path to the installed script.

Comment: It doesn't matter how the script is installed, just how it is invoked.

Comment: I guess I am asking if I am running a pip installed Python app, is it invoked by absolute or relative path. All am doing at the command line is typing the script name.